# Is there another way of keeping score for our Golf group?

Tags: golf, scoring

I play with the same people five days a week in a private Golf club. We play two better balls of a foursome, one in a threesome, paying Front, Back & Overall.
The same few people get most of the points every day, yet they post their scores faithfully every day .
Obviously the GHIN System isn't working for us. Is there any other way of knowing a player potential? Is there another way of keeping score for our Golf group?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way of knowing a player potential?

I would separate the groups and play as individuals in X-somes from time to time. Playing better ball would "mask" a golfer's weakness, especially if one golfer consistently gets the better ball in his/her group.

> Is there another way of keeping score for our Golf group?

Mostly unaware of how "official" systems work (ie, GHIN looks official with respect to recording scores and calculating handicap), I would suggest the [stableford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stableford) scoring system for your group (playing as individuals). Stableford rewards better scores insofar that they have a greater reward than the penalty worse scores possess. "Player potential" would be observed through weighing the ratio of rewards and penalties the stableford system provides.

Unlike stroke play, birdies are hard enough to come by but scoring a 10 on the hole isn't...at least for the casual golfer. A 10 among otherwise good golf would be weighed down in stroke play, but not necessarily in stableford.

If you need an "official" way to calculate handicap, perhaps stroke play can be recorded on the side. That would be a lot to keep track of, but this would freshen up the scoring among your group.